# How to round half up

Tags: php, rounding

I was wondering what php function could help me to do what I am looking for. I want to round number to the half up.

For example:

```
1.16 => 1.5,
0.5 => 0.5
1 => 1
```

I wanted to use round function like this :

```
round(1.16, 0.5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

But it returns `1` instead of `1.5`. I probably dont understand well what the function is doing.

Comment: Also, you can't round to _half a digit_. `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` says that you will round to the higher number if you are exactly halfway between two candidates, not that it will round to halves. You need a bit of maths for that one, not just a function.

Comment: Needs details or clarity.

Comment: `I want to round number to the half up.` You probably meant to the nearest half up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option.  We can multiply the input number by 2, then take the ceiling, and finally divide by two, e.g.

```
$input = 1.16;
$input_rounded = ceil(2*$input) / 2;
echo $input_rounded;
```